# Not to redirect action cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

When i click **Save This Job** Button, There is redirect to Jobsaves/savejobs/1. How to do not to redirect, stay on this page job/view/1

In Jobsaves Controller

```
 if ($this->Jobsaves->save($jobsave)) {
               $this->Flash->success(__('The jobsave has been saved.'));
                //return $this->redirect();
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The jobsave could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
```

in Jobs/View/1

```
<?php echo $this->Html->Link('Save This Job',['controller'=>'Jobsaves','action'=>'savejob',$job->id],['class'=>'btn btn-success']); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should redirect to referer like this:

```
if ($this->Jobsaves->save($jobsave)) {
               $this->Flash->success(__('The jobsave has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect($this->referer());
} else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The jobsave could not be saved. 
Please, try again.'));
}
```